# Remove boundaries BottomNavigationView for ripple effect

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android, ripple, ripple-effect

I want the ripple effect to go beyond the bounds of the `BottomNavigationView`. How can i do this?

I have this xml:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.To assign Null value for the Bottom Navigation Instance at runtime. Please Try this,

xml:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            android:elevation="0dp"/>
```

java:

```java
BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navView.setBackground(null);
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

To Assign Null value for the background property in xml.

**android:background="@null"**

*Like this,*

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@null"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```